# Arithmetic of Cuspidal Reps. Fundamental non split stratum and simple stratum

Tags: rt.representation-theory, local-fields, p-adic, supercuspidal-representations

I started to read Colin Bushnell's notes on this title. The last theorem in the 3rd section claims that if $\pi$ is an irr. smooth rep. of $GL_N(F)$ containing a non-split fundamental stratum, then $\pi$ contains a simple stratum.

The first step in the proof is to show that one can assume that the non-split fundamental stratum $[\mathfrak{a},n,n-1,b]$ contained in $\pi$ is such that $e(\mathfrak{a})$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

I think that there is a mistake in this proof:
[The proof in the notes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsIbk.png)

The containment of the unit subgroups is seem to be (clearly) the other way around and not as mentioned.

Is there a work around or other way to prove it?

Thanks,
Zahi.

Comment: You're totally right. There is a mistake. Let me think about how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have a reference for these notes? Where did you find them ?

Comment: Thanks @PaulBroussous. I could only find [this link](http://www.ecsponline.com/yz/B8D5ED3EFD17D4D85B93EDFD10B7C1963000.pdf). Microsoft Edge could handle the fonts in my computer. The Theorem is on page 25 of the pdf (page 16 in Bushnell's notes).